# Blender Mapping Drivers not Updating until Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, drivers

I have a rig that uses drivers for a facial panel. The rig has one UV texture for its eyes, so I want to move the driver to change the eyes. Ive used a mapping node in my material, and this is what my nodes look like:[image: Node Setup]

If I manually change the mapping coords, it updates in the material view, but when I use the driver to change, it doesnt update until render. Does anyone know to how to fix >.

Comment: Not sure but I think it's a known limitation of Blender's current viewport material system. Materials are never animated in viewport in real time. GLSL materials are optimized for speed, not interactivity, so animations are stripped away.

Comment: That's too bad... I wanted to do this very thing too. I'd like to animate the UV coordinates for 2D eyes in Blender using a bone, and then import the bone animation to a game engine to drive the  texture's UV offset there.